# Working with IShellFolder from multiple threads

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

I want to call `IShellFolder.EnumObjects` from the background thread to avoid freezing the GUI thread in case enumerating takes extensive amounts of time.

The `IShellFolder` interface is obtained (and used) in the GUI thread. What is the proper way to pass its pointer to the background thread?

1. Marshal the interface pointer using `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`?
2. Directly pass the interface pointer to another thread?

What about returned PIDL's - can they be safely exchanged between the threads?

Threads use STA threading model.

Comment: I don't believe you can use the IShellFolder in another in another thread. The shell interfaces can't be marshalled, and aren't free threaded so options 1 and 2 won't work. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/287087#/en-us/kb/287087 PIDLs (strictly speaking the list the pointer refers to) are global so they can be exchanged with other threads and other processes.

Comment: Create and use the `IShellFolder` interface in the thread and it's all good

Comment: @Ross The article refers to multi-threaded apartment, while in my case I use several (2-3) single-threaded apartment threads. Tests show that both  options work... But I'm still interested if it's the correct way to accomplish the task.

Comment: @David I thought about it, but as the interface is already obtained in the main thread, I thought maybe I can save some CPU cycles and re-use it?

Comment: Not with the threading model you can't. PIDLs are fine to pass across threads.

Comment: @djsoft The article addresses your situation. It says shell interfaces can't be marshalled. That means if 1) actually works, you're relying on unsupported/undocumented behaviour. For 2) to work reliably the interface needs to be free threaded, but if the interface was free threaded it would work in MTA apartments without marshalling. Note that even if 1) was well defined, it wouldn't do what you want. It would result in any call made using the marshalled interface on the non-GUI thread being forwarded to back to the GUI thread.

Comment: Ross, David, thanks for the comments! I believe I have an answer now.